# Converting floating point (double) from Java to JRuby on Rails to SQL

Tags: java, sql, ruby-on-rails, floating-point, jruby

I am writing a library in Java so I can use it in JRuby on Rails with a MySQL database. Should I use `float` or `double` to represent the floating point that is eventually going to end up as the `:decimal` model type in Rails ActiveRecord?

More explicitly:

- double converts to a DOUBLE PRECISION
- float converts to a FLOAT

But since only `:decimal` is [supported in ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#supported-types), which Java primitive maps to that?

Comment: I see :float supported in ActiveRecord

Comment: What do you mean by "only :decimal is supported in ActiveRecord"? The link you provided shows float on there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent in Java is the BigDecimal class.  There is no primitive for this.